# What're variable.methodName() functions/methods called?

Tags: python, string, class, methods

Super simple question: What are these types of methods/functions called?

```
"Some random string".upper()
"A string in python".lower()
"A formatted string {}".format("in Python")
```

I really tried looking up everything I could and how I could make them, but as far as I know, they're called 'class methods', which is as broad a term as the sky. I asked my CS teacher, but even he didn't have a real answer for me.

Comment: i mean, they ARE class methods. the thing to realise though in this case, is that the class in question is `str`

Comment: I had a feeling that it would be something like this, but I wasn't able to find details. I was probably searching for `String` instead of `str`.

Answer (score 0):

They are all `builtin_function_or_method`:

```
>>> type('ABC'.lower)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>>
```

but there are more like string methods tho

And these are `method_descriptor`:

```
>>> type(str.lower)
<class 'method_descriptor'>
>>>
```

Use `type` to do this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

These are called instance methods, since they operate on instances of a class, in this case `"Some random string"` is an instance of the `str` class, and the `upper()` method directly operates on that instance itself.

A good way to distinguish them is to ask yourself, does the method need information about a particular instance? For example, does `upper()` need to know about the text in a particular string instance to do its job?

In comparison, class methods do not operate on a particular instance of a class. For example, https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes

> Return the integer represented by the given array of bytes.
>
> ```
> >>> int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x10', byteorder='big')
> 16
> >>> int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x10', byteorder='little')
> 4096
> >>> int.from_bytes(b'\xfc\x00', byteorder='big', signed=True)
> -1024
> >>> int.from_bytes(b'\xfc\x00', byteorder='big', signed=False)
> 64512
> >>> int.from_bytes([255, 0, 0], byteorder='big')
> 16711680
> ```

In this case, the method `from_bytes` does not need information about any particular instance of the int class, since it is the one constructing an instance.